# Android: Transition with transparent background on Button

Tags: android, xml, animation, button

**Edit**

Some code I tried:

The code for the activity:

```
AnimationDrawable buttonAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_testning);

    ImageView animationView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonTestView);
    if(animationView != null) {
        animationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) animationView.getDrawable();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        buttonAnimation.start();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Drawable test.xml (Rect and Line_bottom are rectangle and bottom line that can be seen below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/rect" />
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="-4dp" >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/line_bottom" android:gravity="bottom"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Drawable text_end.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="-2dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/rect" />
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="-4dp" >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/line_bottom" android:gravity="bottom"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It is important that the rectangle moves down to the line and not that they move together. Then next step is to add text to it as well, not reached that step however.

----------- Old -----------

I am trying to design a button that will transition when you click on it. The button (shown below) is two parts. A box with the text and a line below it. When you press the button the box should slide down to the line.

I tried to build this with shapes and/or bitmaps in a layer-list, but it does not work. Anyone have any idea of how to do it?

It is important that it is animated and not only another image shown when clicked.

Here are the images:

[image: Button before it is clicked] [image: Button when it is clicked]

Comment: can you post some code you've tired?

Comment: @KevCron Done it now! Sorry!